# Start a service from a service class in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Is it possible to start a service class from another service class?

```
 Intent localIntent =  new Intent("com.example.android");
                startService(localIntent);
```

I have tried the above code but I do not think it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to start a service class from another service class?

AFAIK, you can start a service from any `Context`.

> I have tried the above code but I do not think it works.

Well, hopefully your service does not have an `<intent-filter>` for an action string of `com.example.android`. Use an explicit `Intent` to identify your service (e.g., `new Intent(this, YourServiceClass.class);`).

Comment: How to get the context from the current service? This is what i cannot figure out.

Comment: @Aurel: `Service` inherits from `Context`, just as `Activity` inherits from `Context`. Call `startService()` on the `Service` itself.

Comment: I am trying to do it like this but I get an error`Intent localIntent =  new Intent(this,SendLocation.class);
                startService(localIntent);`

Comment: @Aurel: Your code is inside a `Runnable`. `this` therefore refers to the `Runnable`. If this is an inner class of the `Service`, replace `this` with `WhateverYourServiceNameIs.this`.

Comment: I figured it out, I used `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`, thanks

Comment: @Aurel: Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know **exactly why** you should be using `getApplicationContext()`. In this case, you do not need it, so please do not use it.

Comment: What you suggested works too, I will use that. Thanks for the help